# Dont aggregate entire column if selecting distinct pk's with order by pk and limit

Tags: clickhouse

I have a clickhouse table *events* containing 50M rows for a year period (duplicates possible)

```sql
    create table events (
        event LowCardinality(String),
        event_time DateTime64(3),
        uid       String
    ) engine=ReplacingMergeTree() toYYYYMM(event_time)
        primary key (event, event_time)
        order by (event, event_time, uid)
```

When I try to select the first 500 distinct rows clickhouse processes all of them (50M)

```sql
    select distinct event, event_time 
    from events 
    where event='some_event' and event_time between '2020-02-24 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-02-24 00:00:00.000' 
    order by(event, event_time) desc limit 500
```

So it basically *groups by event, event_time* 50M rows before applying a limit to them. Is it possible to force clickhouse not to read data for the entire period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE events
(
    `event` LowCardinality(String),
    `event_time` DateTime,
    `uid` String
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(event_time)
ORDER BY (event, event_time, uid);


INSERT INTO events SELECT
    'ev',
    toDateTime('2020-01-01 00:00:00') + toIntervalSecond(number),
    randomPrintableASCII(5)
FROM numbers(30000000);
    
    
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT event_time
    FROM events
    WHERE (event = 'ev') AND ((event_time >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00') AND (event_time <= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'))
    ORDER BY
        event DESC,
        event_time DESC
    LIMIT 1 BY event_time
)
LIMIT 500
.....

Elapsed: 0.008 sec. Processed 1.07 million rows
```